# Catching a fast slug of metal in space

Tags: science-based, physics, space

You have a mass driver which throws a 1 kg slug of iron at your spaceship. The slug reaches your spaceship and at that time it is going 30 km/s relative to the spaceship. You intend for the spaceship to harvest some of the momentum of the slug, allowing the spaceship to accelerate somewhat without spending propellant. The slug will then continue on, somewhat slower than before. What is the best way to harvest momentum from the slug?

The slug must not be melted or otherwise destroyed because it is aimed so that it will eventually orbit back to where it can be caught and re-used.

The catcher can't be too close to the slug because of the danger of a collision. We can suppose that the spaceship tracks the slug and maneuvers very accurately to catch it, but for safety no part of the catcher mechanism should be within 1m of the slug.

A large [eddy current brake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current_brake) might harvest some momentum from an iron slug. However, this is somewhat limited for this scenario because it turns the slug's kinetic energy into heat in the slug. Braking an iron slug from 2 km/s to 0 with an eddy current brake would unfortunately melt it.

The slug has to be iron.

A good solution should harvest a lot of momentum from the slug, and also should not weigh too much. We might say the entire spaceship should weigh no more than 1000 tons.

Comment: Why not use a conductive material with a higher melting point, like tungsten ?

Comment: Is this setup built only to propel the ship?

Comment: Why not use a laser and sail? It's much more accurate, more efficient, and you can fire the laser continuously, which takes a lot of pressure off your materials and design. And it's not like you have to worry about running out of photons.

Comment: Answer? It's proprietary. Can't tell ya. Though it definitely isn't a shipboard laser battery that blows the slug into atoms, catches the ion wind with a magnetic sail, then launches an identical slug on the right trajectory.

Comment: @Cadence photons are a rubbish way to transfer momentum, and lasers are significantly less efficient than linear electromagnetic motors. Charged particle beams or pellet streams are a plausible way of giving good accelerations without the need for stupendous death ray grids and awkward sails.

Comment: `The slug does not have to be iron; it could be any material suitable for shooting out of a mass driver.` This is a problem. You don't define the mass driver and you don't define the slug. That means it can be non-ferrous materials, like rocks. That leaves one and only one way to capture the slug and convert its momentum into energy: mechanical capture. That's the only way to not care about the mass driver or the material of the slug. But it has a consequence, it changes the vector of the ship. Theoretically, magnetic capture wouldn't do that. Please [edit] your post to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: @JBH Clarified that you can choose the slug material as part of your solution.

Comment: @causative That doesn't work on Stack Exchange. That makes the question Opinion-Based (a reason to close the question). You need to make the choice because, in Stack Exchange's view, there can be only one best answer. Note that the [help/on-topic] discourages brainstorming questions and the [help/dont-ask] forbids questions where all answers have equal value (which is what you did).

Comment: @causative Please act quickly to ask just one well-focused question. My badge status gives me a 95% chance of closing your question with a single vote. I'm trying not to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Is the slug thrown in anticipation of some of its kinetic energy being harvested?  Because *any* interaction that changes its kinetic energy will change its orbit, so the only way it can be aimed to orbit back to any particular point is if all the details of the energy transfer are accounted for at the time it is thrown.

Comment: @JBH Very well, then I'll say the slug has to be iron. It's a matter of what system will achieve the goal of transferring momentum to the ship, and the system includes both the slug and the catcher. But, whatever.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, it's thrown in anticipation and for the purpose of being harvested, and yes, the details of energy transfer are accounted for at the time it is thrown. Minor course corrections for the slug could be done with land-based lasers. Thrown from Mars orbit at a few km/s -> 30 km/s when it passes Earth due to the Sun's gravity well -> some speed harvested by a passing spaceship -> course adjusted by Earth's gravity back towards Mars -> slows down to a near-stop by the time it reaches Mars again and is caught by a satellite to be thrown again.

Comment: 'You have a mass driver which…' works only if you held back vital information. Did you mean 'there is…'?

Why try to harvest 'some' momentum, not all of it?

Isn't the ship accelerating without spending propellant simply a 'slingshot effect', which hardly needs all that explanation?

Isn't the slug returning to be re-used more important and more interesting than anything else here?

Isn't that largely impossible, depending on the ship following a prescribed course so closely, the question became irrelevant? How could the catcher ever be too close?

More…

Comment: Further… Far from supposing, you would be constrained by the fact of the ship tracking the slug accurately enough to catch it, however close your catcher mechanism came.

Why mention an eddy current brake, only to rule it out?

Why does the slug have to be iron?

If your ship should weigh no more than 1,000 tons and a good solution 'should not weigh too much', how much would you say it should weigh?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin (1) You don't want to harvest all momentum because the slug needs to have exactly enough momentum left to orbit around to where it can be re-used. (2) Slingshot effect normally means gravity assist. This is similar but with an artificial slug not a planet, and with EM not gravity. (3) yes, the ship and slugs must both follow a very carefully prescribed course. (4) The ship's catcher shouldn't be too close because there is some uncertainty in the position of the slug. If the slug impacts the ship it's game over. So you need a safety margin.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin (5) I'm not ruling out an eddy current brake, just pointing out an issue with it. It might still be the best solution, I'm not sure. (6) The slug has to be iron because JBH said so, no other reason. I originally wanted to say the choice of slug material could be part of your solution but JBH said no. (7) The ship's weight includes the catcher, so a good solution for the ship's catcher should not be more than the weight of the ship, 1000 tons. We're dealing with nearest order of magnitude here, not exact engineering solutions.

Comment: Actually, JBH made some partly-opinionated interpretations of the rules, and the two of you got confused about iron, non-ferrous metals and rocks are. Because rocks demand a mechanical grab doesn't at all mean the slug needs to be iron… merely that metal might be better.

Comment: Actually, melting doesn't mean destruction, nor anything close. In this context, melting might change the shape, and thus the centre of gravity. How else could melting hurt?

Comment: Quite separately, what would be the point of using a 1Kg slug of anything? Of course velocity could give 1Kg huge energy, and how exactly do either mass or velocity of the slug compare to the ship's?

Answer (score 9):

If your mass driver used electromagntic acceleration systems (eg. it was a [coilgun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coilgun)) you can use the exact same techniques to decelerate a slug as you used to accelerate it in the first place. You're effectively treating the slug as the moving bit in a giant electric motor, and electrical motors can be run in reverse during [dynamic (or regenerative) braking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_braking), which is *not* the same as simple eddy-current braking, as most of the heat will be generated in the spacecraft rather than the slug. Some heating will occur in the slug suring both acceleration and deceleration, but you can always just brake less aggressively and throw more slugs to make up for it. In the limit, this starts looking a bit like a [space fountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_fountain). You can reduce heating further by using superconducting projectiles instead of dumb iron slugs, but that adds its own issues and increases the required tech-level.

It is worth remembering that this sort of technique does not seem to have been considered for real-world spacecraft propulsion, and that should raise a red flag or two. If nothing else, 30km/s is fairly modest as far as fancy interplanetary travel goes, and it seems likely that a science-fictionally effective nuclear-electric rocket could outperform it (in duration, if not necessarily initial acceleration).

You can see similarities with pellet-beam propulsion... [NIAC](https://www.nasa.gov/about-niac/) just awarded a phase 1 grant to some research on this: [Pellet-Beam Propulsion for Breakthrough Space Exploration](https://www.nasa.gov/general/pellet-beam-propulsion-for-breakthrough-space-exploration/). I'm more interested in stuff like [MagBeam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MagBeam) myself, but it is a somewhat more sophisticated system with lower [technological readiness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_readiness_level)

Comment: (1) Yes, I started off wondering, "what if a space fountain didn't stop at the edge of space?" Specifically a fountain from Earth orbit to Mars orbit and back. (2) Nuclear rockets use up mass, whereas a fountain like that could keep shuttling ships back and forth indefinitely on just solar power (plus a minor amount of mass spent on maneuvering thrusters). (3) An electric motor design sounds good, and the slug can have windings, but I wonder, how big would the catcher have to be?

Comment: No need to infer any "red flags" from lack of serious consideration. This design has some fairly obvious challenges. You need to aim the slugs with extremely good accuracy, and if you're off by very little it could instantly destroy the spaceship...

Comment: "Using up mass" is a funny complaint... there's a lot of dumb mass out there. You might not be "using it up", but you're creating a giant hazard to spaceflight... think how much mass you need to have in-flight, and have a think about how tiny speed-and-direction errors result in wide error margins for pellets at a moderately distant target  and _colossal_ catcher requirements on the return trip. Your proposal seems slooooooow and awkward and hazardous in a way that eg. magbeam or nuclear rocketry or various kinds of sails aren't. Still, its nice to see new and different ideas popping up!

Comment: The slugs can be very hazardous. But that makes the ingredients for a good story right?

Comment: If you really manage to catch those, you will end up with free reaction mass for another acceleration phase: just fire them out of the same... barrel, that was used to catch them. But then you would need to start thinking about what at the other end of the iron slug assisted internal/external propulsion system sits (in short, who fires those slugs, and what does it do to not experience the same acceleration by itself?)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a space elevator cable suitable for visiting small planets with no atmosphere. String is always useful. Let us assume this is buckytube cable which can lift 1000 Kg on Earth gravity. Under this tension, the cable will accelerate a 1000 ton ship at about 1 cm/s2, which would be gentle enough not to spill your tea. At the other end, this will decelerate your 1Kg slug at 1000 m/s2, which is 100 x Earth's gravity. Deceleration would take 300 seconds, or 5 minutes.

With these figures, you will need 450 Km of cable. You will also have to be very careful about jerking: climbers' ropes have breaking strengths in tons force because they have to handle the deceleration when the rope suddenly goes tight. Buckytube cables are not springy so they will be vulnerable to this. The cable also has to take the strain for accelerating itself as well as the slug, and I haven't included this. I have chucked your precaution of saying no part of the catcher mechanism is to be within 1m of the slug, because I don't think it should apply here.

450 KM is a lot of cable, but not absurd if you were carrying one anyway as a space elevator. If the slug was going less fast (say 10 KM/s) you could make do with 50 Km, as this goes as the square of the velocity.

Your captain can probably figure out how to do this if they look at a history website for how they cleared Earth's orbit of old, junk satellites back in the 2060's.

I added a bit on avoiding the jerk in a comment, and I am now copying it here. To avoid the jerk, see 'Moby Dick': you chuck the harpoon and then let the line run through a tight grip with thick gloves. This pulls back on the target you have attached to, but not so suddenly that you break the line or pull out the harpoon.

I think this proposal lies somewhere between 'pretty hard' and 'just about possible'. I think it might lose out to other schemes unless you had the apparatus for other purposes, such as an elevator, or hunting space whales.

Comment: How do you attach the cable to the slug? It comes preattached? Like you're holding the cord to someone's harpoon gun? These launch mechanisms are getting out of hand.

Comment: @BMF I had imagined some sort of net to catch the slug. I had assumed the slug was just a random lump of stuff, and nothing fancy.

Comment: A net to catch something moving 30 km/s? That's some net.

Comment: If you are catching these slugs and bringing them. on board, they could be part of your cargo. In which case, the ship starts off lighter and can accelerate more. What you are shipping would have to be pretty shock-resistant. No, the figures aren't exactly encouraging, I'll admit.

Comment: 1000 ton ship accelerating at 1 cm/s^2 = (1e6 kg) (1e-2 m/s^2) = 1e4 kg m/s^2 = 1e4 N force.

1 kg slug decelerating at 1000 m/s^2 = 1e3 kg m/s^2 = 1e3 N force.

You have a factor of 10 discrepancy here between forces that should be equal and opposite, possibly from mixing up "kilograms force" with newtons. This then affects the rest of your calculations. 

That issue aside, it's not at all clear to me *how* you're spacing this momentum transfer out into a nice gradual process. If the cable is not springy, surely we should expect a sudden jerk when it runs out of slack.

Comment: @GBsupportsthemodstrike I may have slipped the ten from Earth's G somewhere. I hope someone will check my working before building the spaceship. For avoiding the jerk, read 'Moby Dick': you harpoon the whale and then let the line run through a tight grip. This will pull back on the target you have attached to, but not so suddenly that you break the line or lose the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Heat can be a source of energy, also, as it is in Stirling engines.

Make your tube *very* long, curved if need be, and alternate your tube between eddy current braking, and "cooling" sections in which the excess heat is also captured as a source of energy. The melting point of iron is 1538C, arrange your sections to only heat the slug to 1200C, and then capture that heat long enough to reduce it to perhaps 500C, and repeat the eddy brake, then the Stirling heat capture, etc.

Comment: How are you transferring the heat from the slug to the Stirling engine? If I've done the physics correctly, it should take approx. 5 minutes for a near-spherical 1kg iron slug to cool from 1200C to 500C by radiative loss. At a relative speed of initially 30 km/s, this means just the first cooling section would need to be on the order of 9000 km long. This creates some practical difficulties. Increasing its surface area e.g. elongating the slug will reduce that time proportionally, but it also makes it more fragile, which could be a problem for something undergoing huge mechanical forces.

Comment: @GBsupportsthemodstrike I'd say elongate the slug. Make it long rod. I did say a *very* long tube, perhaps the tube can be filled with a thin gas or transfer agent, for direct contact.

Comment: The thinner the gas, the less useful it is as a heat transfer medium, and at high temperatures radiative loss dominates over conduction/convection. (Radiation scales with the fourth power of temperature, whereas conductive loss scales linearly.) Even at 1 atm, I think gas would only make a very marginal improvement to cooling time. Meanwhile, you're dealing with some very exciting kinetic effects as the 30km/s slug hits that gas. Larger area will again improve cooling but will also exacerbate those effects.

Comment: @GBsupportsthemodstrike Okay. stick with the very long slug. This is science fiction, we don't need to explain every detail of the mechanism. We just need plausibility.